# Git squashed my commit from remote machine, lost commits?

Tags: git, version-control

I had been working on a branch and had committed changes late last night that included an updated test file (Sept 10th).

This morning I was asked to make some minor changes and squash the commits. Unfortunately I did this from a different machine whose last commit was from Sept 8th. So the command I ran was

`git rebase -i head~7`

Which took all the commits made to the local branch and squashed them to one commit, then I did a

`git push remote branch --force`

AFAIK this action orphaned the commits that occured on Sept 9 + 10. However, I can't seem to find any of those commits using `git log`. I want the methods.js file from September 10th. Is there any way to recover it if I can't get the hash?

Comment: from your original machine where you made the change, if you run `git log master..` (replace master to the branch you have committed your changes) you are not able to retrieve the commit ?

Comment: I'm working remotely - I can probably fix it when I get home tonight but I was hoping to fix it from the remote machine.

Comment: if you did not push the changes, they will remain in your local repo. can you set your remote machine as a repo and connect from your work machine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `git reflog` to find where HEAD where pointing before your rebase.

You can also use `git fsck --unreachable` to find orphan objects that is not referenced by a named reference (i.e. branch or tag).

Comment: @CBauer, you may also try `fsck`,  see my updated answer.